# Dispatching an action from another action

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Let's say I've got these Flux actions;

```js
{
  "type": "USER_LOADED",
  "payload": { ... }
}
```

```js
{
  "type": "USER_LOAD_FAILED",
  "payload": { ... }
}
```

```js
{
  "type": "SHOW_ERROR_MODAL",
  "payload": { ... }
}
```

```js
{
  "type": "HIDE_ERROR_MODAL"
}
```

I've got a `UserStore` (which listens to `USER_LOADED` and `USER_LOAD_FAILED` and updates accordingly) and a `ModalStore` (which listens to `SHOW_ERROR_MODAL` and updates accordingly).

I have a `Modal` component which is always present on the page, which renders content from the `ModalStore`.

What's the best way of showing an error modal when `USER_LOAD_FAILED` occurs? Should by `ModalStore` listen to it? I am going to end up with a lot of different types of `*_LOAD_FAILED` actions, so is this a good idea?

I can't dispatch from the `UserStore` in response to `USER_LOAD_FAILED`, as you can't dispatch during a dispatch.

I *could* dispatch from some "Controller" component, which does something along these lines;

```js
class UserController extends PureComponent {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.state = { error: null, notified: false };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => this.props.flux.store('UserStore').on('change', this.onUserChange)

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    if (this.state.error && !this.state.notified) {
      this.props.flux.actions.showErrorModal(this.state.error);

      this.setState({ notified: true });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount = () => this.props.flux.store('UserStore').off('change', this.onUserChange)

  onUserChange = () => {
    const userStore = this.props.flux.store('UserStore');

    // UserStore#getError() returns the most recent error which occurred (from USER_LOAD_FAILED).
    const error = userStore.getError();

    this.setState({ error, notified: error !== this.state.error });
  }

  render = () => ...
}
```

But I feel like this is just a workaround as opposed to an actual solution.

---

One last way I thought of was to just dispatch a `SHOW_ERROR_MODAL` inside the action creator which originally dispatched `USER_LOAD_FAILED`, but I still don't know if this is the "advised" way, as you could end up putting lots of logic in there for other cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Promises to make API calls, if you dispatch actions in your resolve or reject functions, it will not be triggered during the current dispatch.

Same is the case with callbacks. By the time your resolve/reject/callback functions execute, your original dispatch will have completed.

Having said that, I'm not sure why you chose to have your modal component be driven by a store. Are you making any API calls or doing some other processing before showing the modal? If not, perhaps you can consider showing/hiding your modal based on the state of your component.